# Delete request not working in React+Express+MongoDB app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

im working through fullstackopen course along TOP, every excercise went well so I drifted off the course to build simple todo app to solidify the knowledge i gained so far. So i developed front end with react, then the back end with node express connected to mongoDB. All seemed fine but then the delete request stopped working - every other request works fine, only the delete causes errors. After requesting a delete the page crashes, BUT in the database the request is fulfilled and the note is removed. So when I reconnect to the node server and refresh the page, the content is up to date and everything seems to work again.

RESTclient is saying that delete request works fine. But in the browser, when i click delete button, after like a second the app crashes and this is shown in the console:

```
Notes.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')
    at Notes.js:20:27
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at b (Notes.js:19:16)
    at xo (react-dom.production.min.js:167:137)
    at Pi (react-dom.production.min.js:197:258)
    at Eu (react-dom.production.min.js:292:88)
    at bs (react-dom.production.min.js:280:389)
    at gs (react-dom.production.min.js:280:320)
    at vs (react-dom.production.min.js:280:180)
    at ls (react-dom.production.min.js:271:88)
```

server.js:

```
    require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Note = require("./models/note");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("build"));
app.use(express.json());
app.set("json spaces", 2);

app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("tiny"));

/// DEFINE DEFAULT PORT //
const PORT = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

/// DEFINE BASIC ROUTES
app.get("/notes", (request, response, next) => {
  Note.find({}).then((notes) => response.json(notes));
});

app.get("/notes/:id", (request, response, next) => {
  Note.findById(request.params.id)
    .then((note) => {
      if (note) {
        response.json(note);
      } else {
        response.status(404).end();
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => next(error));
});

/// DELETE ///
app.delete("/notes/:id", (request, response, next) => {
  Note.findByIdAndRemove(request.params.id)
    .then((response) => response.status(204).end())
    .catch((error) => next(error));
});

/// UPDATE ///
app.put("/notes/:id", (request, response, next) => {
  const {content, done} = request.body

  Note.findByIdAndUpdate(
    request.params.id,
    {content, done},
    {new: true, runValidators: true, context: "query"},
  )
  .then(updatedNote => response.json(updatedNote))
  .catch(error => next(error))
})

/// ADD ///
app.post("/notes", (request, response, next) => {
  const body = request.body;

  if (!body.content) {
    return response.status(400).json({
      error: "content missing",
    });
  }

  const note = new Note({
    content: body.content,
    done: false,
  });

  note
    .save()
    .then((saved) => response.json(saved))
    .catch((error) => next(error));
});

/// HANDLE UNDEFINED ROUTES ///
const unknownEndpoint = (request, response) => {
  response.status(404).send({ error: "unknown endpoint" });
};

app.use(unknownEndpoint);

/// HANDLE ERRORS ///
const errorHandler = (error, request, response, next) => {
  console.error(error.message);

  if (error.name === "CastError") {
    return response.status(400).send({ error: "malformatted id" });
  } else if (error.name === "ValidationError") {
    return response.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
  }

  next(error);
};
app.use(errorHandler);
```

front-end,
app.js:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import css from "./App.css"
import Button from "./Button";
import Input from "./Input";
import noteService from "./services/NoteService";
import Notes from "./Notes";

function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [newNote, setNewNote] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    noteService.getAll().then((response) => {
      setNotes(response);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    const content = event.target.value;
    setNewNote(content);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const note = { content: newNote, done: false };
    noteService
      .create(note)
      .then((response) => setNotes(notes.concat(response)));
    setNewNote("");
  };

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    noteService
      .trash(id)
      .then(setNotes(notes.filter((note) => note.id !== id)));
  };

  const toggleStatus = (id) => {
    const note = notes.find((item) => item.id === id);
    const updated = { ...note, done: !note.done };
    noteService.update(id, updated).then((response) => {
      setNotes(notes.map((note) => (note.id !== id ? note : response)));
    });
  };

  const showDone = () => {
    noteService.getAll().then((response) => {
      setNotes(response.filter((note) => note.done));
    });
  };

  const showUndone = () => {
    noteService.getAll().then((response) => {
      setNotes(response.filter((note) => !note.done));
    });
  };

  const showAll = () => {
    noteService.getAll().then((response) => {
      setNotes(response);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      
      <h1>TO_DO NOTES</h1>
      <div className="header">
      <Input action={handleInput} value={newNote} />
      <Button text={"Add"} action={handleSubmit} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button text="Show All" action={showAll} />
        <Button text="Show Done" action={showDone} />
        <Button text="Show Undone" action={showUndone} />
      </div>
      <Notes notes={notes} action={handleDelete} toggle={toggleStatus}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Notes.js:

```
import Button from "./Button";
import css from "./Notes.css";

const Note = ({ item, action, toggle }) => {
  return (
    <li
      onClick={() => toggle(item.id)}
      className={item.done ? "done" : "undone"}
    >
      {item.content} <Button text="x" action={() => action(item.id)} />
    </li>
  );
};

const Notes = ({ notes, action, toggle }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {notes.map((item) => (
          <Note key={item.id} item={item} action={action} toggle={toggle} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default Notes;
```

NoteService.js:

```
import axios from "axios";

const baseUrl = "/notes";

const getAll = () => {
  const request = axios.get(baseUrl);
  return request.then((response) => response.data);
};

const create = (newObject) => {
  const request = axios.post(baseUrl, newObject);
  return request.then((response) => response.data);
};

const update = (id, newObject) => {
  const request = axios.put(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, newObject);
  return request.then((response) => response.data);
};

const trash = id => {
  const request = axios.delete(`${baseUrl}/${id}`)
  return request.then(result => result.data)
}

export default {
  getAll,
  create,
  update,
  trash,
};
```

I would really appreciate some help. I compared this project with the other one i have thats structured the same, the other one is working but here cannot figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Literally what's happened is that you're accessing `notes.map((item) => (Note key={item.id}`... but `item` is null so you can't get `item.id`.   So, the next step would be to investigate `notes` and see what its elements are to confirm that one or more of them are indeed null.  Then you must figure out how null items got into `notes` in the first place.  Presumably one of the `setNotes` calls is responsible.  Do some debugging and find it.

Comment: tried it, when i console log(item) everything is fine and it shows few note objects with valid id's, nothing suspicious

Comment: If `Notes.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id') at Notes.js:20:27` is still happening then you need to add `const Notes = ({ notes, action, toggle }) => { console.log(JSON.stringify(notes)); return /*etc...*/`

Comment: [{"content":"gitara siema","done":true,"id":"6335d348ce42ec055612a0e7"},{"content":"aaa","done":false,"id":"633686a086748f550c773040"},{"content":"ssss","done":false,"id":"633686a286748f550c773042"}]

this is the output, worth noting that it is logged twice in a row from the same file

Comment: Well I'm not sure what could be going on.  It looks like `notes` contains 3 objects and all 3 of them have an `id` property, so I don't get why it's saying `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')`.  There must be some details you're not disclosing or some mistake you've made in your debugging.  Can you please turn this into a runnable snippet that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Can you try putting a console. log for the argument id inside handledelete function?
before calling the noteservice.trash() method.

Can you check if id is being correctly provided to the function

Answer (score 0):

In the Notes.js file within the Notes component, where you are iterating using notes.map, change it to `notes?.map` and see if that works.

Comment: throws same error